# Can´t install SonarLint in Eclipse Helios

Tags: eclipse, installation, equinox, sonarlint

Im trying to install SonarLint in Eclipse Helios running with java 1.8, but i can´t because this error

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=PlatformProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,  action=).
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.sonarlint.eclipse.cdt,3.4.0.201803051332.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5025020467099366276.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5025020467099366276.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.sonarlint.eclipse.cdt.source,3.4.0.201803051332.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile9163845847876620088.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile9163845847876620088.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.sonarlint.eclipse.core,3.4.0.201803051332.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile3621115035794508733.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile3621115035794508733.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.sonarlint.eclipse.core.source,3.4.0.201803051332.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8606114277852919692.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8606114277852919692.jar
Problems downloading artifact: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.sonarlint.eclipse.feature,3.4.0.201803051332.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2655109718785619107.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2655109718785619107.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.sonarlint.eclipse.jdt,3.4.0.201803051332.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8458927802726569508.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile8458927802726569508.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.sonarlint.eclipse.jdt.source,3.4.0.201803051332.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5715438942136023438.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5715438942136023438.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.sonarlint.eclipse.m2e,3.4.0.201803051332.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile676493239203346947.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile676493239203346947.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.sonarlint.eclipse.m2e.source,3.4.0.201803051332.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile781867365499640931.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile781867365499640931.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.sonarlint.eclipse.ui,3.4.0.201803051332.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile565391622856465198.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile565391622856465198.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.sonarlint.eclipse.ui.source,3.4.0.201803051332.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5260017800383208637.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile5260017800383208637.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.sonarlint-client-api,3.1.1.1436.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile632890418940769004.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile632890418940769004.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.sonarlint-core,3.1.1.1436.
Error reading signed content:C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2609752615460184090.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: C:\Users\japerezg\AppData\Local\Temp\signatureFile2609752615460184090.jar
```

Comment: Eclipse Helios is **9** years old, it is quite likely that this code won't run on it.

Comment: why eclipse helios, why can't you go with newer version of eclipse. You won't need additional change to start using the further versions of eclipse.

Comment: Because is an existing maven project from other company that was created in helios and compiled with jdk 6. And i read that SonarLint supports jdk8, thats why i´m running eclipse  with jdk 8. But I´m new on the company and on using maven and SonarLint, i will ask why we can´t update Eclipse.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is from the eclipse market place  -

eclipse support for sonar lint -

```
2019-03 (4.11), 2018-12 (4.10), 2018-09 (4.9), Photon (4.8), Oxygen (4.7), Neon (4.6), Mars (4.5), Luna (4.4)
```

Find more details here -

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/sonarlint

So you need to upgrade to at least - eclipse LUNA